# When I use dynamic_cast and delete the object delete , how the destructor works?

Tags: c++, c++11

I create a object of derived class and a base class point for it , 
and then I use the dynamic_cast convert base class point to derived class point .
   I delete the derived class point , but the program calls the derived destructor and the base destructor. Why does the program call the base destructor? After all, the base destructor isn't a virtual function....

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


class con {
private:
    double num;
public:
    con() {
        num = 0;
        cout << "default..." << endl;

    }
    void getnum() {
        cout << num << endl;
    }
};




class base {
public:
    virtual void A() {
        cout << "it is base A" << endl;
    }

    void B() {
        cout << "it is base B" << endl;
    }

    ~base() {
        cout << "it is base decon" << endl;
    }
};


class child : public base {
public:
    void A() {
        cout << "it is child A" << endl;
    }

    void B() {
        cout << "it is child B" << endl;
    }

    ~child() {
        cout << "it is child decon" << endl;
    }

};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    base* b = new child();
    child* c = dynamic_cast<child*>(b);
    delete c; //the program print "it is child decon"   "it is base decon"
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should really make the destructors virtual!

Comment: You do not need a virtual destructor if you delete allways the concrecte type. But as @Someprogrammerdude said: don't do it.

Comment: I don't know why the program calls the derived destructor and then calls the base class destructor even though I didn't make the base class destructor virtual ....I had thought it should only call the derived destructor. Thank you...：-）@manni66

Comment: Ah.  Now I have understood. The derived class always calls the derived   destructor and the base class destructor.. Thank you @manni66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: If you delete a pointer derived class, it always calls the destructor of the derived class first, then the destructor of the base class.

Case 2: If you delete a pointer to the base class of a derived class with a ***non-virtual*** base class destructor, it doesn't know about the derived class so it just deletes the base class.

Case 3: If you delete a pointer to the base class of a derived class with a ***virtual*** base class destructor, it uses virtual dispatch to the destructor of the derived class, then calls the destructor of the base class.

Case 2 is bad.  It can cause resource leaks, etc.  It should be avoided by always declaring destructors virtual in classes that are intended to be base classes.

Your example illustrates case 1.

If you want to see case 2 in action try `delete b` rather than `delete c` in your example.

Comment: Thank you so much ... The case2 like my example is bad because it can cause resource leaks... What's more , I want to ask another related question, in order to avoid the resource leaks we use the virtual base class destructor , is there any other method to avoid resource leaks expect the virual base class destructor method when I use the base class point to derived class... (It's a interview question for me ....). Thank you. @DaleWilson

Comment: If for some reason you cannot declare the base class destructor as virtual, you could make it protected so `delete b` would be a syntax error.   If you can't change the base class at all you could use private inheritance  or you might embed the base class as a member rather than inheriting from it, but you might have to forward methods from your derived class to your base class.   As a last resort you can have a strongly enforced coding standard that says never use `delete b` or we'll cut off your supply of free coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Destructors in C++ don't "overload" as such; they chain up. When you say

```
{
    child c;
}
```

then at the closing brace the compiler will insert a call to `~child()`, which will in turn call `~base()` (and the destructors of other base classes, if you had them). This is essential to avoid memory leaks -- otherwise how would `base`'s members be destroyed? Note that this doesn't require the `base` destructor to be `virtual`.

This works the same way when you manually destroy something with `delete`:

```
child* c = new child{};

delete c; // runs ~child(), which calls ~base()
```

again, this doesn't require the destructor to be `virtual`.

What a virtual destructor *does* do is allow you to destroy a variable with dynamic type `child` using a pointer to a `base`, i.e.

```
 child* c = new child{}
 base* b = c;
 delete b; // Will call ~child() if destructor is virtual, otherwise ~base()
```